# Most clean and efficient way to generate and zip two lists in Python

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Given these two lists

```
zeros = [2,3,1,2]
ones = [3,4,5]
```

(with the condition that always `len(zeros) == len(ones) + 1`)

I want to create one list with alternating 0's and 1's of the magnitude mentioned in the list. I can achieve this by:

```
zeros_list = [[0]*n for n in zeros]
ones_list = [[1]*n for n in ones]
output = [z for x in zip(zeros_list, ones_list) for y in x for z in y]
output += [0]*zeros[-1]
print(output)
> [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

Is this however the most efficient / clean way? I get a performance of 2.66 µs ± 78.8 ns, but I still have the idea this could be done in a one-liner, and maybe more efficient

Comment: is it an option using numpy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two apparently faster solutions, using the "trick" to special-treat the *first* zero rather than the last, using it to initialize `output`.

```
def superb_rain(zeros, ones):
    zeros = iter(zeros)
    output = [0] * next(zeros)
    for o in ones:
        output += (1,) * o
        output += (0,) * next(zeros)
    return output
```

```
def superb_rain2(zeros, ones):
    z = iter(zeros).__next__
    output = [0] * z()
    for o in ones:
        output += (1,) * o
        output += (0,) * z()
    return output
```

(As @schwobaseggl pointed out, tuples made it about 30% faster.)

Benchmark results:

```
0.14 us  0.13 us  0.13 us  baseline
3.04 us  3.02 us  2.98 us  original
3.27 us  3.19 us  3.29 us  chepner_1
5.03 us  5.12 us  5.25 us  chepner_2
4.66 us  4.74 us  4.68 us  chepner_2__superb_rain
2.52 us  2.53 us  2.47 us  Alain_T
3.35 us  3.27 us  3.42 us  python_user
1.02 us  0.99 us  1.04 us  superb_rain
1.07 us  1.11 us  1.09 us  superb_rain2
```

Benchmark code:

```
import timeit
from itertools import zip_longest, cycle, islice, repeat, chain

def baseline(zeros, ones):
    pass

def original(zeros, ones):
    zeros_list = [[0]*n for n in zeros]
    ones_list = [[1]*n for n in ones]
    output = [z for x in zip(zeros_list, ones_list) for y in x for z in y]
    output += [0]*zeros[-1]
    return output

def chepner_1(zeros, ones):
    return list(chain.from_iterable(chain.from_iterable(zip_longest((repeat(0, x) for x in zeros), (repeat(1, x) for x in ones), fillvalue=[]))))

def roundrobin(*iterables):
    "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
    # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
    num_active = len(iterables)
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).__next__ for it in iterables)
    while num_active:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            # Remove the iterator we just exhausted from the cycle.
            num_active -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, num_active))
def chepner_2(zeros, ones):
    zero_groups = (repeat(0, x) for x in zeros)
    one_groups = (repeat(1, x) for x in ones)    
    return list(chain.from_iterable(roundrobin(zero_groups, one_groups)))
def chepner_2__superb_rain(zeros, ones):
    return list(chain.from_iterable(map(repeat, cycle([0, 1]), roundrobin(zeros, ones))))

def Alain_T(zeros, ones):
    return [B for N,P in zip(zeros+[0],ones+[0]) for B in ([0]*N+[1]*P)]

def python_user(zeros, ones):
    res = [None] * (len(ones) + len(zeros))

    res[::2] = ([0]*n for n in zeros)
    res[1::2] = ([1]*n for n in ones)

    res = [y for x in res for y in x]
    return res

def superb_rain(zeros, ones):
    zeros = iter(zeros)
    output = [0] * next(zeros)
    for o in ones:
        output += (1,) * o
        output += (0,) * next(zeros)
    return output

def superb_rain2(zeros, ones):
    z = iter(zeros).__next__
    output = [0] * z()
    for o in ones:
        output += (1,) * o
        output += (0,) * z()
    return output

funcs = [
    baseline,
    original,
    chepner_1,
    chepner_2,
    chepner_2__superb_rain,
    Alain_T,
    python_user,
    superb_rain,
    superb_rain2,
    ]

zeros = [2,3,1,2]
ones = [3,4,5]
number = 10**5

expect = original(zeros, ones)
for func in funcs:
    print(func(zeros, ones) == expect, func.__name__)
print()

tss = [[] for _ in funcs]
for _ in range(4):
    for func, ts in zip(funcs, tss):
        t = min(timeit.repeat(lambda: func(zeros, ones), number=number)) / number
        ts.append(t)
        print(*('%.2f us ' % (1e6 * t) for t in ts[1:]), func.__name__)
    print()
```

Comment: Using tuples shaves another 30% of the times: `output += (1,) * o`

Comment: it was nice to let this run and watch as the names came up, cool, take a +1

Comment: @schwobaseggl Thanks, confirmed and updated :)

Answer (score 4):

Zip with a list comprehension should do the trick.

```
zeros = [2,3,1,2]
ones = [3,4,5]

output = [B for N,P in zip(zeros,ones+[0]) for B in [0]*N+[1]*P]

print(output)

[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

*Note the `ones+[0]` is to ensure that you don't drop the last value from the zeroes list in the zip operation.*

Comment: Why `zeros+[0]`?

Comment: But we're guaranteed that `zeros` is longer.

Comment: It would also seem odd, given that we start with zeros and thus if `ones` was longer, its last two streaks would really only be *one* streak. Like, [3] and [2,4] should just be [3] and [6] then.

Comment: That's right. I didn't think that one through.  So there are no scenarios where 'zeros+[0]' would be useful.  I'll remove that ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.chain`, `zip_longest`, and `itertools.repeat` to create a not-too-confusing one-liner.

```
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(chain.from_iterable(zip_longest((repeat(0, x) for x in zeros), (repeat(1, x) for x in ones), fillvalue=[]))))
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

On my machine, this took 3.34µs. More importantly, it's the wrapper to `list` that takes this time. The iterator itself produces the elements on demand, if you don't actually need them all at once.

---

```
list(chain.from_iterable(
        chain.from_iterable(zip_longest((repeat(0, x) for x in zeros),
                                        (repeat(1, x) for x in ones),
                                        fill_value=[]))))
```

- `(repeat(0, x) for x in zeros)` creates a sequence of `repeat` objects that represent your runs of 0s; likewise to create the groups of 1s.
- `zip_longest` zips them together into a sequence of pairs, adding a do-nothing empty list to balance the extra value in `zeros`
- `chain.from_iterable` flattens that sequence (from `(a, b), (c, d)` to `(a, b, c, d)`.
- The outer `chain.from_iterable` then flattens the `repeat` objects in to a single sequence, which `list` turns into a list.

---

You can also simplify the one-liner using the `roundrobin` recipe from the `itertools` documentation, which handles both merging the zero groups and one groups, as well as the first round of flattening.

```
from itertools import cycle, islice, repeat, chain

zeros = [2,3,1,2]
ones = [3,4,5]

# From the itertools documentation
def roundrobin(*iterables):
    "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
    # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
    num_active = len(iterables)
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).__next__ for it in iterables)
    while num_active:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            # Remove the iterator we just exhausted from the cycle.
            num_active -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, num_active))


zero_groups = (repeat(0, x) for x in zeros)
one_groups = (repeat(1, x) for x in ones)
    
print(list(chain.from_iterable(roundrobin(zero_groups, one_groups))))
```

Comment: Ok, replacing `zip` with `zip_longest` was simpler than I was thinking, but I think using `roundrobin` is interesting as well if you don't count the definition of `roundrobin` against the one-liner. :)

Comment: A variant: `list(chain.from_iterable(map(repeat, cycle([0, 1]), roundrobin(zeros, ones))))`

Comment: @superbrain Much nicer, though a little bit slower (4.88µs on my machine)

Comment: I don't think I ever bothered timing my `roundrobin` solution, only the `zip_longest` one.

Comment: But again, I don't think the time matters much if you can take advantage of the laziness to only use the values as they are generated: `for x in chain.from_iterable(...): # do stuff with x`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I had overlooked your first solution. Included it now in my benchmark. Yes, that one is faster. My version of your second is only faster than your second.